# Recovering from a separate (now corrupt) SVN repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

So for some reason (miscommunication for what the actual subversion URL is and only 1 person working on the code previously) we have two different subversion repositories with what we want to be the same code. Basically the timeline went like this:

1. Created X repository
2. Put code in
3. Created Y repository
4. Put code from X in
5. Made modifications to Y
6. SVN repo Y got corrupted (so he just stopped committing.. not bothering to say something before the backups replaced themselves)
7. I made changes to X

And, so now I need to somehow merge the changes from Y into X. What would be the best method for doing this?

Comment: OT: just out of interest: how can you corrupt a repository? What is your error message? Which revisions are broken? All? I am very interested, as I am searching for an example of a real life corruption of a svn repository

Comment: @Peter `corrupt node-revision 'm2g-5.0.r5/[long number]' missing id field in node-rev` or `'REPORT of '/svn/MyProject/!svn/vcc/default': could not read chunk size` or a few other error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a branch from x at the revision where y was created
- put the code from y in that branch
- commit
- merge the 'branch-y' to your trunk in x