# SVN revision corrupted

Tags: apache, svn, backup

My SVN revision 22026 is corrupted. I have verified by using svnadmin verify command. I manually verified the 22026 file in db\revprops and in \db\revs folder. 22026 file is empty in revprops folder but content is available in revs folder. It looks like revision 22026 property file is corrupted or empty.

I have used RSYNC backup so my backup also having same issue. How to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 2 things:

Dump you repo and load it again ignoring properties:

```
svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH > full.dump
svnadmin load --bypass-prop-validation NEW_REPOS_PATH < full.dump
```

If above doesn't work, exclude your problematic revision, as described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873648/1023562):

```
$ svnadmin dump -r1:22025 my_repos > dumpfile.dump
$ svnadmin dump --incremental -r22027:HEAD my_repos >> dumpfile.dump
$ svnadmin load my_repos_new < dumpfile.dump
```

Since you wrote *"content is available in revs folder"* you might be able to apply this revision by hand once you recover your repo.

Comment: I think first option is not possible because while export the whole repo I am getting error @ 22026. So I will try option 2. In option 2 method, we skipping one revision so finally one revision count will be reduced. For example my last revision is  170973 after skipping the revision my last revision number would be 170972.  It will affect the whole repo?

Comment: Yes. But you can separate `dump` in 2 files, load first, commit one dummy revision and then load second `dump` file.That way rev numbering will remain as it was in the old repo.